# Transforming a 2x4 array into a 4x2, and copying all the elemets

Tags: c++, arrays, c, sorting

I've been going at this piece of code for the past couple of hours, and I haven't really figured out how I can do what I need to do, basically I'm trying to copy the elements of the 2x4 array into the 4x2

input array:

```
{1,3,5,7}
{2,4,6,8}
```

output desired:

```
{1,5}
{2,6}
{3,7}
{4,8}
```

what I've tried so far

```
int arr1[4][2];
int arr2[2][4];
int x,y;


for (x=0; x<4; x++){
    for(y=0; y<2; y++){
        arr1[x][y] = arr2[y][x];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how i can approach the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: If the pairing is ALWAYS the same, you could just skip the loop and do it manually. That said, by what logic do you do your pairing? Which element is supposed to go where? Once you figure that rule out, you can adjust your loop accordingly.

Comment: by pairing do you mean that 4x2 into 2x4, and how would I that, lets assume that I don't know the array row or column indices, then I dont think that would possible

Comment: Well, there's got to be some sort of rule behind the sorting, otherwise this becomes an impossible task. In your example, you always paired 1/3 and 2/4 of each array.
That's your rule. Now all you need to do is tell your computer about it.

Comment: Are you sure that your example is correct? At first, I thought that this was a simple transposition (in  the algebra sense). But looking at your example, it is a totally different thing. For transposition, your code seems correct

Answer (score 1):

I am with @fern17 that you example is probably incorrect, and that you need a transpose which you implemented correctly.

If your example is correct, then you need to figure the function that maps input indexes to output indexes.  This following would do but I don't know how that generalizes to other sizes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int src[2][4] = {
        {1,3,5,7},
        {2,4,6,8}
    };
    int dst[4][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            dst[i][j] = src[i % 2][2 * j + i / 2];
            printf("%d%s", dst[i][j], j + 1 < 2 ? ", " : "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

which would give you this output:

```
1, 5
2, 6
3, 7
4, 8
```